# Удалить из строки все символы кроме букв и цифр в Java

Tags: java, java-ee

Помогите! Не могу удалить из строки все символы кроме букв и цифр. В начале у меня static метод для удаления символа а потом код не рабочий.
Спасибо

```
public static String removeChar(String s, char c) {
       String r = "";
       for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i ++) {
          if (s.charAt(i) != c) r += s.charAt(i);
       }
       return r;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Введите свой текст: ");
    String self = sc.nextLine();

    for (char ch : self.toCharArray()) {
        if ( !Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch) ) {
            n++;
            removeChar(self, ch);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Количество других символов: " + n);
    System.out.println( self );

}
```

Comment: Вы возвращаете r , а дальше почему - то с им ничего не делаете

Comment: весь код одна сплошная ошибка, сначала хотел поправить, но это нереально =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для таких задач лучше пользоваться [регулярными выражениями](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).
Код будет значительно проще и понятнее.

```
String self = getString();//как-нибудь получаем строку
String result = self.replaceAll("\\w|\\d", "")//регулярным выражением заменяем буквы(\\w) и цифры(\\d) на пустую строку, то есть удаляем.
```

Comment: Вот интересно, автор просит **оставить** только буквы и цифры, а Вы **их удаляете**, но он (автор) принимает ответ, как правильный.

Comment: @avp  Очень страноо

Comment: И вообще `"\\w|\\d"` = `"\\w"`, которое находит буквы (ASCII), цифры (ASCII) и `_`

Answer (score 9):

вот так можно попробовать

```
String s = "буквы,символы,цифры и тд и тп";
s = s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9]", ""); // удалится все кроме букв и цифр
```

Comment: Угу, а букву Ё забыли. И буквы всех других алфавитов тоже забыли.

Answer (score 7):

[@Luchnik](/users/5344/luchnik), Вы были не верном пути.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String... av) {

        String s = "  --abc  678 .. Z";

        System.out.println("End "+delNoDigOrLet(s));
    }

    private static String delNoDigOrLet (String s) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (Character .isLetterOrDigit(s.charAt(i)))
                sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Самый, имхо, логичный ответ из всех. Будет быстрее любого из методов, представленных выше. Разве что, может, за исключением случая, когда в строке нет "удаляемых" символов.

Answer (score 3):

сядь и почитай про строки, вместо того чтобы фигню писать

```
String resultString = str.replaceAll("some char", "some other char");
```

**UPD1**

а чем мой вариант не подходит? что мешает вместо букв/цифр ставить первым параметром знаки?

код может не работать =)

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String... av) {

        String s = "  --abc  678 .. Z";

        System.out.println("End "+delNoDigOrLet(s));
    }

    private static String delNoDigOrLet (String s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(s.charAt(i)))
              String str = s.replaceAll(str.charAt(i), "");

        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Ну или лучше хранить "запрещенные" символы в какомнибуть массиве-словаре и заменять их в строке таким же перебором.

Comment: @Gorets, а как решить **задачу в вопросе**, используя Replace() ?

Требуется, ведь:

    удалить из строки все символы кроме букв и цифр

Вы предлагаете решение, по сути, **обратной** задачи. Однако, кто-то считает, что этот ответ заслуживает внимания.

Comment: @Gorets, все китайские иероглифы тоже будете перечислять ? 

Более того, Вы предлагаете для **каждого** "запрещенного" символа просматривать/перестраивать всю строку. В самом деле ?

--

Возможно данную задачу можно решить, написав отрицание регулярного выражения для Буква-или-Цифра. Я сразу не в состоянии написать его, думаю остальные отвечавшие или читавшие вопрос тоже (в противном случае мы бы увидели его). 

Соответственно программа, реализующая такой метод (даже если она окажется **правильной** (а удостовериться в этом непросто)) окажется **непонятной**, немодифицируемой и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Привет, сам столкнулся с проблемой как убрать из строки все буквы и оставить только цифры. На ответ натолкнула именно эта тема :) Моя модификация на просьбу автора:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 0;
        String textDigits = "";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите свой текст: ");
        String self = sc.nextLine();

        for (char ch : self.toCharArray()) {
            if ( Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch) ) {
                textDigits = textDigits + ch;
            }else{
                n++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Количество других символов: " + n);
        System.out.println( textDigits );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Я за функционалку:

```
private static String delNoDigOrLet(String str) {
    return str.chars()
            .filter(i -> Character.isLetterOrDigit(i))
            .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf((char) i))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так - Удаляет и пробелы.

```
String resultString = str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9 ]", "");
```

Comment: У вас возник новый вопрос? Или что значит приведённая вами строчка кода?

Comment: Это ответ на заданный вопрос.

Comment: Заданый вопрос содержит фразу: удалить из строки все символы **кроме букв и цифр**. Как вы её поняли? Отвечает предложенная вами строка кода на заданный вопрос? Если да, то добавте пожалуйста в ответ воиспроизводимый пример и его вывод.

Comment: Вот изменил.Теперь все правельно.

Answer (score 1):

Если решить задачу с помощью регулярного выражения, то можно воспользоваться

```
String result = self.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]+", "");
```

Если нужно оставить пробельные символы:

```
String result = self.replaceAll("(?U)[^\\p{L}\\p{N}\\s]+", "");
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/WeMDlP/1).

**Подробности**

- `(?U)` - модификатор `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` (не используется в Android!), который в данном выражении позволяет `\s` находить все пробельные символы Юникода, не только ASCII
- `[^` - начало исключающего (отрицающего) символьного класса, он находит любой символ, отличый от заданных в классе:

  - `\p{L}` - любая буква Юникода
  - `\p{N}` - любая цифра Юникода
  - `\s` - благодаря `(?U)` находит любой пробельный символ Юникода
- `]+` - конец символьного класса, 1 и более повторов (для более быстрого удаления).

См. [пример работы кода на Java](https://ideone.com/UL6Q7Z):

```java
System.out.println("Я – робот123!N".replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]+", ""));
// => Яробот123N
```