# Как сделать проверку строки на палиндром?

Tags: java

Задача:

> Реализуйте метод, проверяющий, является ли заданная строка
>   палиндромом. Палиндромом называется строка, которая читается одинаково
>   слева направо и справа налево (в том числе пустая). При определении
>   "палиндромности" строки должны учитываться только буквы и цифры. А
>   пробелы, знаки препинания, а также регистр символов должны
>   игнорироваться.

Не приходит в голову как проигнорить регистр букв, пробелы и всякие запятые...

В методе нельзя использовать цикл.. Подскажите идею.

Answer (score 2):

`StringBuffer` и регулярные выражения вам в помощь:

```
 String s = "PaLi ; Ndr   ,o mmord\"nila;p";
 String punctWhiteSpaceRegex = "[\\p{Punct}]|[\\s]";
 boolean isPalindrom = new StringBuffer(
                      s.replaceAll(punctWhiteSpaceRegex, ""))
                     .reverse().toString()
                     .equalsIgnoreCase(s.replaceAll(punctWhiteSpaceRegex, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Данная тема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/103640/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2-java) поможет удалить все посторонние символы кроме букв и цифр из выражения, а [эта тема](http://www.cyberforum.ru/java-j2se/thread1240394.html) поможет в проверке на палиндром, в итоге можно составить такой код:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String s = " z  --abc  67876 ..cba Z";
    s = s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9]", "");
    if (s.toLowerCase().equals((new StringBuilder(s)).reverse().toString().toLowerCase()))
        System.out.println("Палиндром! " + s);
    else
        System.out.println("Не палиндром! :( " + s);
}
```

Comment: условие можно сократить if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString()))